# Brezis' exercise 8.30.2: $a$ is a continuous and coercive bilinear form on $V$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. Let $k \in \mathbb R$ such that $k \neq 1$. We consider the space
$$
V := \{v \in H^1 (I) : v(0) = kv(1)\},
$$
and the symmetric bilinear form $a$ defined on $V$ by
$$
a(u, v) = \int_I [ u'v' + uv ]  - \left ( \int_I u \right) \left ( \int_I v \right).
$$

I am trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> **Exercise 8.30**
>
> 1. Check that $V$ is a closed subspace of $H^1 (I)$.
>
> In what follows, $V$ is equipped with the Hilbert structure induced by the $H^1$ inner product.
>
> 2. Prove that $a$ is a continuous and coercive bilinear form on $V$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt of (2.). Could you please have a check on it?

---

The continuity of $a$ is easy. Let's prove the coercivity of $a$. We need to find $\varepsilon >0$ such that
$$
a(u, u) = \int_I [ |u'|^2 + |u|^2 ]  - \left ( \int_I u \right)^2 \ge \varepsilon \|u \|_{H^1}^2 = \varepsilon \int_I [ |u'|^2 + |u|^2 ],
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
(1-\varepsilon) \int_I [ |u'|^2 + |u|^2 ]  \ge \left ( \int_I u \right)^2.
$$

We have $\left ( \int_I u \right)^2 \le \int_I |u|^2$, so it suffices to find $\varepsilon >0$ such that
$$
(1-\varepsilon) \int_I [ |u'|^2 + |u|^2 ]  \ge \int_I |u|^2,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\int_I |u'|^2 \ge \frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon} \int_I |u|^2.
$$

For $x \in I$, we have $u(x) - u(0) = \int_0^x u'$ and $u(1) - u(x) = \int_x^1 u'$. We have $ku(1)-u(0)=0$, so $(1-k) u(x) = \int_0^x u' + k \int_x^1 u'$. Then
$$
|u(x)| \le \frac{k+1}{|k-1|} \int_I |u'|,
$$
which implies
$$
\int_I |u|^2 \le \left ( \frac{k+1}{k-1} \right )^2 \int_I |u'|^2.
$$

We just need to pick $\varepsilon >0$ such that
$$
\left ( \frac{k+1}{k-1} \right )^2 \le \frac{1- \varepsilon}{\varepsilon}.
$$