# Does this second-order boundary-value problem have a unique solution when $k=1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. Let $k \in \mathbb R$. We consider the space
$$
V := \{v \in H^1 (I) : v(0) = kv(1)\},
$$
and the symmetric bilinear form $a$ defined on $V$ by
$$
a(u, v) = \int_I [ u'v' + uv ]  - \left ( \int_I u \right) \left ( \int_I v \right).
$$

Clearly, $a$ is continuous. We fix $f \in L^2 (I)$ and consider the problem
$$
(1) \quad
u \in V
\quad \text{and} \quad
a(u, v)=\int_I f v
\quad \forall v \in V,
$$
which (by integration by parts) is equivalent to
$$
(2) \quad
\begin{cases}
-u'' + u-\int_I u = f \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
u(0)=k u(1) \text { and } u'(1)=k u'(0).
\end{cases}
$$

In case $k \neq 1$, I have [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824802/brezis-exercise-8-30-2-a-is-a-continuous-and-coercive-bilinear-form-on-v) that $a$ is coercive and thus $(1)$ has a unique solution by Lax-Milgram theorem.

> Now we assume $k=1$. Does $(1)$ have a solution? If yes, is it unique?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for sure that if $f\equiv 0$, any constants are solutions to (2) for $k=1$ and hence in this case, (2) does not have unique solution. If $f$ is a non-zero constant, it is also easy to see that (2) does not have a solution. For nonconstant $f$, for example, $f(t)=t$, then
$$
(*)\quad\begin{cases}
-u'' + u-\beta = t \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
u(0)=u(1) \text { and } u'(1)=u'(0).
\end{cases}
$$
has the solution
$$ u(t)=-\frac{2 (e-1) (\beta +t)+e^{1-t}-e^t}{2-2 e}. $$
Applying $\int_Iu=\beta$ gives
$$ \frac12+\beta=\beta $$
which is absurd. Therefore (*) does not have solution for $f(t)=t$.

Update: In order for (2) to have solution, one must impose the condition $\int_If=0$. Even under this, the solution of (2) is not unique. For example, let $f(t)=t-\frac12$ which satisfies the condition. It is not hard to see that
$$
(**)\quad\begin{cases}
-u'' + u-\beta = t-\frac12 \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
u(0)=u(1) \text { and } u'(1)=u'(0).
\end{cases}
$$
has the solution
$$ u(t)=-\frac{2 (e-1) (\beta-\frac12 +t)+e^{1-t}-e^t}{2-2 e} $$
which satisfies $\int_Iu=\beta$ for any constant $\beta$. Therefore (**) has infinite many solutions.

Comment: Do you know the well-posedness of $(1)$ in case $f$ is not a constant?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: If $f$ satisfies $\int_If=0$, (2) may have infinite many solutions. See the update.

Comment: Thank you so much for your recent detailed answers!