# Brezis' exercise 8.30.7: what happens to the sequence $(u_n)$ if $k_n \to 1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. Let $k \in \mathbb R \setminus \{1\}$. We consider the space
$$
V := \{v \in H^1 (I) : v(0) = kv(1)\},
$$
and the symmetric bilinear form $a$ defined on $V$ by
$$
a(u, v) = \int_I [ u'v' + uv ]  - \left ( \int_I u \right) \left ( \int_I v \right).
$$

I am trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> **Exercise 8.30**
>
> 1. Check that $V$ is a closed subspace of $H^1 (I)$.
>
> In what follows, $V$ is equipped with the Hilbert structure induced by the $H^1$ inner product.
>
> 2. Prove that $a$ is a continuous and coercive bilinear form on $V$.
> 3. Deduce that for every $f \in L^2 (I)$ there exists a unique solution of the problem
>    $$
>    (1) \quad
>    u \in V
>    \quad \text{and} \quad
>    a(u, v)=\int_I f v
>    \quad \forall v \in V.
>    $$
> 4. Show that the solution $u$ of $(1)$ belongs to $H^2 (I)$ and satisfies
>    $$
>    (2) \quad
>    \begin{cases}
>    -u'' + u-\int_I u = f \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
>    u(0)=k u(1) \text { and } u'(1)=k u'(0).
>    \end{cases}
>    $$
> 5. Conversely, prove that any function $u \in H^2(I)$ satisfying $(2)$ is a solution of $(1)$.
> 6. Let $k_n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$ for all $n$. Assume $k_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} k \neq 1$. Set
>    $$
>    V_n = \{v \in H^1(I) : v(0)=k_n v(1)\} .
>    $$
>    Given $f \in L^2 (I)$, let $u_n$ be the solution of
>    $$
>    (1_n) \quad
>    u_n \in V_n
>    \quad \text { and } \quad
>    a(u_n, v) = \int_I f v
>    \quad \forall v \in V_n .
>    $$
>    Prove that $u_n \to u$ in $H^1 (I)$, where $u$ is the solution of $(1)$. Deduce that $u_n \to u$ in $H^2 (I)$.
> 7. What happens to the sequence $\left(u_n\right)$ if $k_n$ converges to $1$?

I am trying to solve (7.). I have [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824802/brezis-exercise-8-30-2-a-is-a-continuous-and-coercive-bilinear-form-on-v) that
$$
a(v, v) \ge \varepsilon_n \| v \|_{H^1},
\quad \forall v \in V_n,
$$
where $\varepsilon_n := \frac{(k_n-1)^2}{2(k_n^2+1)}$. This implies $\| u_n \|_{H^1} \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon_n} \|f\|_{L^2}$. We have $\varepsilon_n \to 0$, so I guess $(u_n)$ diverges in $H^1 (I)$. However, I could not prove it.

> Could you elaborate on (7.)?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u_n, u$ be the solutions of
$$
\begin{cases}
-u'' + u-\int_I u = f \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
u(0)=k u(1) \text { and } u'(1)=k u'(0).
\end{cases}
$$
for $k=k_n,1$, respectively; namely
$$
\begin{cases}
-u_n'' + u_n-\int_I u_n = f \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
u_n(0)=k_n u_n(1) \text { and } u_n'(1)=k_n u_n'(0),
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\begin{cases}
-u'' + u-\int_I u = f \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
u(0)=u(1) \text { and } u'(1)=u'(0).
\end{cases}
$$
Let $v_n=u_n-u$ and then $v_n$ satisfies
$$
-v_n'' + v_n-\int_I v_n =0 \quad \text {on} \quad I.
$$
which has the general solution
$$v_n=\beta_n+c_1^{(n)}e^t+c_2^{(n)}e^{-t}\tag{*}$$
where $\beta_n,c_1^{(n)},c_2^{(n)}$ are constants depending on $n$. Note
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
v_n(0)&=&u_n(0)-u(0)=k_n u_n(1)-u(1)\\
&=&k_nv_n(1)+(k_n-1)u(1)=k_nv_n(1)+o(1),\\
v_n'(1)&=&u_n'(1)-u'(1)=k_nu_n'(0)-u'(0)\\
&=&k_nv_n'(0)+(k_n-1)u'(0)=k_nv_n'(0)+o(1),\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now using (*) one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\beta_n+c_1^{(n)}+c_2^{(n)}&=&k_n(\beta_n+c_1^{(n)}e+c_2^{(n)}e^{-1})+o(1),\\
c_1^{(n)}e-c_2^{(n)}e^{-1}&=&k_n(c_1^{(n)}-c_2^{(n)})+o(1),\\
\end{eqnarray}
from which one can get
\begin{eqnarray}
c_1^{(n)}&=&-\frac{\beta_n(k_n-1) (e k_n-1)}{k_n^2+e^2 \left(k_n^2+1\right)-4 e k_n+1}+o(1),\\
c_2^{(n)}&=&
   \frac{e\beta_n(e-k_n) (k_n-1)}{k_n^2+e^2 \left(k_n^2+1\right)-4 e k_n+1}+o(1).
\end{eqnarray}
Clearly if $\{\beta_n\}$ is bounded and $\lim_{n\to\infty}k_n=1$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}c_1^{(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}c_2^{(n)}=0. $$
From this one can conclude that if $\beta_n\to\beta$, then $v_n\to\beta$ as $n\to\infty$.